# How to rename an existing FortiGate VDOM

Tags: fortigate

I need to rename an existing Fortigate 100D VDOM. I cannot find the command unless it's really counter-intuitive. Furthermore, if this is not possible, can I copy the existing VDOM to a new one with the correct name?

Comment: Did the answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Be forewarned, you will probably need to reboot the Fortigate for the changes to take place.

1. Backup your entire config (not just the vdom)
2. Open the config in a text editor
3. Do a Search and replace of the old vdom name with the new name.
4. Save the config under a new name, so that you have a backup of the old config.
5. Restore the new config.
6. Your vdoms should now be renamed.